# Random Streaks in Appearing Only in Final Render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, tracking, compositing-nodes

My rendered animation shows a large streak on some of the frames, and not on others. The streak doesn't show in the viewport, only in the final render. Rendered using cycles.

Here is what the Render should look like. It's relatively normal.

[image: What it should look like (this is the same file, just later in the animation)]

Now earlier in the animation, there is a large streak up. (Image cropped for file size issues)

[image: Same file, different frame, very noticeable streak.]

Here's the mug part of the composite.

[image: Mug part of the composite.]

Here's the shadow part of the composite. (Can't be seen over black background)

[image: Shadow part of the composite.]

Here are the composite nodes used. They are the default for motion tracking. I haven't changed them.

[image: Composite nodes (default for motion tracking)]

Comment: Isn't that just motion blur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you, susu, it was just motion blur. Turning it off fixed the problem.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/112484)

Comment: @Nate_Sycro27 i can’t accept a comment. there is no check

Comment: You simply just mark your own answer as correct.

Comment: @Nate_Sycro27 i can’t for 2 days